# Print whole log starting with special character

Tags: linux

Im trying to print some logs from a logfile for an alarm reporting tool,i need to filter only those starting with a special caracter like ** .
Please find here an example of some texts from the logfile.(picture)

Till now i managed to print logs between SOH characters as below but im not able to find out how to print only those starting with "**" ,so i want to print ones as shown below"

Logfile content:

```
      SOH
     +++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
    ** ALPHA EDFJDJFKLJDKFJKSDLFJL
       SDFSDGDRGRTG
       WEFETTFYRT #168113++-
   SOH 
       +++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
    * KJENRFKES DFJKLSDFJEDFJDJFKLJDKFJKSDLFJL
       SDFSDGDRGRTG
       WEFETTFYRT #168113++-
   SOH 
       +++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
    CL mesukww juwaehdiearfa
       SDFSDGDRGRTG
       WEFETTFYRT #168113++-
    SOH
       +++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
    *C KJENRFKESDFJ ksludhieokdaewmdp
       SDFSDGDRGRTG
       WEFETTFYRT #168113++-
    SOH
     +++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
    ** ALPHA EDFJDJFKLJDKFJKSDLFJL
       SDFSDGDRGRTG
       WEFETTFYRT #168113++-
```

---

Till now I managed to print the log between SOH characters(above log) via

cat OMlog5|awk -F'[|^A^A]'> Test3

---

I tried also below command, filtering those starting with ^*,but it prints out only the specific line starting with *, not whole log

result of:

```
cat OMlog5|awk -F'[|^A^A]' '{print $0}'|grep "^*" >Test4 :


** KDHFGJHSDGDJLKSGJKFJJ
```

I expect to be:

```
 +++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
** KJENRFKESDFJKLSDFJEDFJDJFKLJDKFJKSDLFJL
   SDFSDGDRGRTG
   WEFETTFYRT #168113++-
```

can you please help on finding the right command ?

### thank you in advance!

I'm trying to avoid printing e specific record , for example the log related to "ALPHA". I tried via this code but not succesfull:

```
cat logfile |grep -v "ALPHA"> result_log
```

aft this one ,it prints me out :

```
+++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
       SDFSDGDRGRTG
       WEFETTFYRT #168113++-
```

I want that above whole log related to alpha to not be printed.
can you please help?

Comment: It gets confusing when you add a new requirement to the question with an accepted answer after some time. **I suggest to revert the change here.** Instead write a new question with a link to this one and an explanation of the difference or the additional requirement. Show the example input for the new requirement, the filtering script you actually use until now (without the new requirement) and your proposed modification or additional script/command. In `cat logfile |grep -v "ALPHA"> result_log` it is not clear if `logfile` is your original log file or the result of the first processing step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this is a little bit more easy to remember and works just in case the log format is consistent regarding the number of lines:

```
awk -F 'SOH' '{print $1}' log.txt | grep -B1 -A2 '^\*\*'
```

The way it works is first by getting groups delimited by `SOH`:

```
$ awk -F 'SOH' '{print $1}' log.txt
+++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
** KJENRFKESDFJKLSDFJEDFJDJFKLJDKFJKSDLFJL
SDFSDGDRGRTG
WEFETTFYRT #168113++-

+++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
* KJENRFKESDFJKLSDFJEDFJDJFKLJDKFJKSDLFJL
SDFSDGDRGRTG
WEFETTFYRT #168113++-

+++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
CL KJENRFKESDFJKLSDFJEDFJDJFKLJDKFJKSDLFJL
SDFSDGDRGRTG
WEFETTFYRT #168113++-

+++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
*C KJENRFKESDFJKLSDFJEDFJDJFKLJDKFJKSDLFJL
SDFSDGDRGRTG
WEFETTFYRT #168113++-
```

Then you could simply use `grep` to get one line before `-B1`  and two after `-A2` from your pattern `^\*\*`:

```
grep -B1 -A2 '^\*\*'
```

That will return from your example:

```
+++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
** KJENRFKESDFJKLSDFJEDFJDJFKLJDKFJKSDLFJL
SDFSDGDRGRTG
WEFETTFYRT #168113++-
```

If you don't care about the first delimiter `SOH` then you could just do:

```
grep -B1 -A2 '^\*\*' log.txt
```

If your log starts with extra spaces you could use this regex:

```
grep -B1 -A2 '^\s*\*\*' | grep -v -- --
```

The extra `|grep -v -- --` is to remove the `--` delimiters

Or if in Linux you could use `--no-group-separator`:

```
grep -B1 -A2 '^\s*\*\*' --no-group-separator
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestion. it works good but I do not understand why it includes also an symbol in the output "--" , between each logs

Comment: _italic_ **bold** `--
+++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
* KJENRFKESDFJKLSDFJEDFJDJFKLJDKFJKSDLFJL
SDFSDGDRGRTG
WEFETTFYRT #168113++-

--
+++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
CL KJENRFKESDFJKLSDFJEDFJDJFKLJDKFJKSDLFJL
SDFSDGDRGRTG
WEFETTFYRT #168113++`

Comment: thanks a lot for your support! the code works but I do not understand why it adds an extra character -- in the beginning of each log?

Comment: @Dominik Hi, does are some grep delimiters, try to pipe the output to `|grep -v -- --` or if in Linux use `--no-group-separator`, check updated answer,

Comment: thank you for your solution, it woks as expected. just one question: is there any other way to print all the lines between separater character ^A(SOH) without counting the lines after ** -grep -B1 -A2 ? cause not all logs do have 3 lines after **. I have some others with more or less than 2 lines after ** ?

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` command will print everything between two `SOH` lines or after the last `SOH` line if this block contains a line that starts with `**` (after optional space).
**Edit**: According to the new requirement the script now searches for lines with exactly two asterisks (`*`) instead of at least two.

```
awk '/^[    ]*SOH[  ]*$/ {                # match SOH line
   if(found && length(buf)>0) print buf;  # print old buffer
   buf="";                                # clear buffer
   found=0;                               # no ** line yet
   skip=1;                                # do not add SOH line to buffer
}
/^[     ]*\*\*[     ]/ { found=1;}        # ** line found. Edit: The second [   ] (with space and tab) makes sure there are exactly two *
{                                         # for any line...
   if(!skip) buf=buf  $0  "\n";           # add line to buffer (except SOH)
   skip=0;                                # do not skip next line
}
END {                                     # to handle matching last record
   if(found && length(buf)>0) print buf;  # print old buffer
}' logfile
```

Note: between the brackets `[   ]` there is a space and a tab. (`[ ^I]`)

When I use a `logfile` with the content shown in the question (below "Logfile content:") as input for the script, the resulting output is

```
     +++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
    ** KJENRFKESDFJKLSDFJEDFJDJFKLJDKFJKSDLFJL
       SDFSDGDRGRTG
       WEFETTFYRT #168113++-
```

The leading spaces are different from the output shown in the question below "I expect to be:" because the logfile content from the question has more leading spaces.

Comment: thank you for solution provided but I think is not the right one for this case.SOH is log separator character ,instead "**"  is part of the log, we can not put it as a condition of start and end off the log. correct if I'm wrong

Comment: @Dominik I do not understand your comment. I just fixed a bug in my script: Inside the `awk` sript between single quotes (`'`) I must not use single quotes in comments, e.g. `# don't` Apart from this the script produces the correct output as shown in the question.

Comment: :Yes you are right, script works perfectly :). thanks a  lot. I missed smth in the script and it did not work at first attempt but now the output is as expected. :)

Comment: @Dominik Please edit your question and add this new requirement. Make clear that you added this later.

Comment: Script works as expected ,thanks a lot. I have a file with logfiles starting with *, ** and others even starting with *****. My request is how to use the script to print only **, how can i force to print only ** and not greater than ** ? can you please help?

Comment: @Dominik Please add all new information **to your question** instead of writing comments only. Provide a log file example that also contains data blocks with more than 2 asterisks. Please look how I edited the script. You can see the changes using the link "edited (some time) ago" link below the answer.

Comment: now its clear. I'm sorry I put just a comment, I didn't know how to do it! Now I got it! thank you

Comment: I would appreciate if you can help on this;https://stackoverflow.com/q/55418557/10562397

Comment: i have just explained in a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55953776/how-can-i-avoid-printing-a-special-record-in-a-logfile