# How to avoid printing a special record in a logfile

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I am trying to print some logs from a logfile, avoiding printing a specific log.

I have a logfile as shown below:

```
SOH
     +++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
    ** ALPHA EDFJDJFKLJDKFJKSDLFJL
       SDFSDGDRGRTG
       WEFETTFYRT #168113++-
   SOH 
       +++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
    * KJENRFKES DFJKLSDFJEDFJDJFKLJDKFJKSDLFJL
       SDFSDGDRGRTG
       WEFETTFYRT #168113++-
   SOH 
       +++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
    CL mesukww juwaehdiearfa
       SDFSDGDRGRTG
       WEFETTFYRT #168113++-
    SOH
       +++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
    *C KJENRFKESDFJ ksludhieokdaewmdp
       SDFSDGDRGRTG
       WEFETTFYRT #168113++-
    SOH
     +++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
    ** BETA EDFJDJFKLJDKFJKSDLFJL
       SDFSDGDRGRTG
       WEFETTFYRT #168113++-
   SOH
    ** Gama EDFJDJFKLJDKFJKSDLFJL
       SDFSDGDRGRTG
       WEFETTFYRT #168113++-
```

I can print the logs between special character SOH and the ones starting with ** with below script:

```
awk '/^[    ]*SOH[  ]*$/ {                # match SOH line
   if(found && length(buf)>0) print buf;  # print old buffer
   buf="";                                # clear buffer
   found=0;                               # no ** line yet
   skip=1;                                # do not add SOH line to buffer
}
/^[     ]*\*\*[     ]/ { found=1;}        # ** line found. Edit: The second [   ] (with space and tab) makes sure there are exactly two *
{                                         # for any line...
   if(!skip) buf=buf  $0  "\n";           # add line to buffer (except SOH)
   skip=0;                                # do not skip next line
}
END {                                     # to handle matching last record
   if(found && length(buf)>0) print buf;  # print old buffer
}' logfile
```

I'm trying to avoid printing e specific record , for example the log related to "ALPHA".

I tried via below code but not successful:

```
cat logfile |grep -v "ALPHA"> result_log
```

result:

```
SOH 
 +++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >

   SDFSDGDRGRTG
   WEFETTFYRT #168113++-

SOH
 +++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
** BETA EDFJDJFKLJDKFJKSDLFJL
   SDFSDGDRGRTG
   WEFETTFYRT #168113++-
SOH
** Gama EDFJDJFKLJDKFJKSDLFJL
   SDFSDGDRGRTG
   WEFETTFYRT #168113++-
```

As you can see above, it seems to print the rest of the log containing "ALPHA"m despite "ALPHA itself".

The expected result should be :

```
       SOH
         +++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
        ** BETA EDFJDJFKLJDKFJKSDLFJL
           SDFSDGDRGRTG
           WEFETTFYRT #168113++-
       SOH
        ** Gama EDFJDJFKLJDKFJKSDLFJL
           SDFSDGDRGRTG
           WEFETTFYRT #168113++-
```

So, it should not print the log containing "ALPHA " at all.

I would appreciate if you can suggest any solution!

Thank you!

Comment: You should provide sample input that contains both records to be printed and records to be skipped. (with and without `ALPHA`) In your current example all records with `**` contain `ALPHA`. You should also show the expected output for your example input. Your text referring to "special character ^A" does not match the example input and the script. If `SOH` actually means the corresponding ASCII character `^A` (<kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) you should make this clear in the text. The script uses the text `SOH`, not the control character. Or leave this out and consistently use the text `SOH`.

Comment: hi! thank you Bodo. I just edit the question as you suggested.